# Cannot access pg_largeobject table although I am the lomowner

Tags: postgresql, export, pg-dump

I am looking for the best way on how to export data from the pg_largeobject table. I don't really understand what's the best way. I don't have access to the superuser, thus a pg_dump doesn't seem to work. Also a select on the pg_largeobject table does not work although I am the lomwoner, this is a little bit confusing to me:

```
myserver::APPLICATION=> SELECT oid as "ID",      
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(lomowner) as "Owner",
  pg_catalog.obj_description(oid, 'pg_largeobject') as "Description"
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_largeobject_metadata   where oid = 3301149;
   ID    |    Owner    | Description 
---------+-------------+-------------
 3301149 | application | 
(1 Zeile)

myserver::APPLICATION=>  \conninfo
Sie sind verbunden mit der Datenbank »mydb« als Benutzer »application« auf Host »myhost« (Adresse »X.X.X.X«) auf Port »5432«.
SSL-Verbindung (Protokoll: TLSv1.3, Verschlüsselungsmethode: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, Bits: 256, Komprimierung: aus)
myserver::APPLICATION=> select * from pg_largeobject where loid = 3301149;
ERROR:  permission denied for table pg_largeobject
myserver::APPLICATION=>
```

I also cannot work with lo_export as I don't have access to the file system. Does anyone have an idea how I can smoothly export the largeobjects from the server and import them locally, so I can work with them in my local development environment? Thank you!

Comment: In psql, you can use `\lo_export` to export to the clients filesystem without needing access to the servers filesystem.  If you are not using psql, then you need to specify what you are using as your client.